# How to design url pattern for /add/id/number

Tags: django

How to design url pattern for:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/id/number

```
url(r'^add/$)
```

number - digits 1-5 (1,2,3,4,5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean:

```
url(
   r'^add/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<number>\d{1,5})/', 
   'add', 
   name="add"
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, if your view accepts a `number` parameter (and number is a single digit):

```
url(r'^add/id/(?P<number>[0-5])$)
```